# Android: GridView with shelves with scroll

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I want to create a GridView with shelves. I have created a class for this:

```
public class ShelveGridView extends GridView{

private Bitmap background;

public ShelveGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bibliotca_image_shelf);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int count = getChildCount();
    int top = count < 0 ? getChildAt(0).getTop() : 0;
    int backgroundWidth = background.getWidth();
    int backgroundHeight = background.getHeight();
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x += backgroundWidth) 
          for (int y = top; y < height; y += backgroundHeight) 
            canvas.drawBitmap(background, x, y, null);


    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}...
```

but when I scroll the GridView, shelves not move. I guess that I have to overwrite some method in this class to move the Bitmap background while I do scroll. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not approaching this correctly.  Setting a background in this way will not make it scrollable. There are several ways to make the background scroll:

1. Set one shelf as a background for a list item
2. Set the horizontal shelf as the divider image and set the back of the shelf as the image for list item.
3. Set the horizontal shelf as the divider image and set the back of the shelf as the background of the listview (as you do now with the whole shelf image).

Method 3 will produce the closest results and this is how apple's iBooks works.

Comment: Thanks you, I'll try with the option 2.

Comment: @Rincha option 2 will produce desired result only if you have enough items to fill the entire area of the list (I loosely consider a grid being a list of rows). If there are empty rows at the bottom, it will look rather funny :)

Comment: @Rincha found answer...?